# Getting a System.Windows.Forms.Window in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, forms, winforms-interop

a few months ago I've started a new windows forms application. Now that I've discovered wpf I would like to use it for all new forms and migrate the old ones if they're refactored.

Within a component I need a *System.Windows.Window*. I know that I've got this if I'm using wpf in all parts. But currently I have a windows forms main-window. So can I get a *System.Windows.Window* from the main window??

It's used for a dialog which should be modal. But currently it isn't because I can't provide a *Window*.

To clarify:

I've got a ProgressDialog:

```
var p = new ProgressDialog(); // from ookii dialogs, signature ShowDialog(Window)
p.ShowDialog(window);
```

After p.ShowDialog(...) I should have a modal window. But I have no idea where to get the window, which should be of type *System.Windows.Window*. The the form where this is called is a normal windows-forms window. But when I try to provide this instead of *window* I get a compile error.

The ProgressbarDialog is the one from the ookii dialogs. (Sorry for irritation)

Comment: [Please note for the future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Cant understand the problem. Is you problem that you cant get `using System.Windows.Window;` "work" in Winform application?

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701680/setting-a-form-as-owner-for-a-window

Answer (score 0):

Method Show() of Progress bar does not accept parameters. Please give more relevant example.