# Setting a WinForms Form as Owner for a WPF Window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winforms

I have a main application which is built around a System.Windows.Forms.Form  There is a legacy System.Windows.Window that the user can call up which is set as Topmost.  I would like the Window to be owned by the main application, so it will minimize when the application is minimized.
So my expected code was

```
TopmostDisplayWindow.Owner = MainAppForm;
```

However, there is no Window.Owner method that takes a Form and Window has no override of Show() that takes the owner.

Is there an easy way to get a Window for the MainAppForm or would it take something more complicated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`WindowInteropHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and set `Owner` property of it:

```
var window = new YourWPFWindow();
WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
helper.Owner = this.Handle;
window.Show();
```

Use the above code in your main/parent form which is a Winform `Form`.
Remember to add following references when you want to show your WPF Window:

1. `PresentationCore`
2. `PresentationFramework`
3. `WindowsBase`